# Asynchronous DataClass running post Exit Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom class in VBA that pulls historical data from Bloomberg. The class, and the Bloomberg objects it uses, are asynchronous and based on the RTD platform.

The issue I'm having is that I run Subs that call this custom class, but the event handling code in the custom class only runs once my Sub is finished.

```
Dim bbHist As New HistDataControl

Sub PullDataAndDoStuff()    
     bbHist.MakeHistRequest StockTicker, "MOV_AVG_50D", startDate, Date    
     Call DoStuffWithTheData
End Sub

Private Sub DoStuffWithTheData()
 ..... 'None of this works, because MakeHistRequest / bbHist class hasn't run
End Sub
```

Is there a way to force Excel to wait until the bbHist has run?

Comment: Does it have a property to check to see if it's done yet? If so, you just put a `DoEvents` in a `Do Until` loop, checking that property.

Comment: I can definitely add a simple True / False in there to throw when done.  I've never used DoEvents though  - do I put that into my main Sub (PullDataAndDoStuff)?

Comment: "I have a custom class in VBA" - seems like we'd need to know something about that class.  Does it fire events for example?

Comment: @braX - your DoEvents worked perfectly.  I can check as the answer if you put it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has a property to check to see if it's done, then you can just put a `DoEvents` in a `Do Until` loop, checking that property for its completion.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the bbg handler waits. 
So the solution is to make your sub wait for the bbg query to end, and then call your processing data sub.
There are plenty of solutions for that on stackoverflow so I'll let you look for that.